# how to get recent event recorded in event logs(eg: logged before about 10 seconds) in Windows using C++?

Tags: windows, winapi, logging

I need to collect event logs from Windows those are logged before 10 seconds. Using pull subscription I could collect already saved logs before execution of program and saving logs while program is running. I tried with the code available on MSDN:

[Subscribing to Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385771.aspx)

"I need to start to collect the event logged 10 seconds ago". Here I think I need to set value for `LPWSTR pwsQuery` to achieve that.

`L"*[System/Level= 2]"` gives the events with level equal to 2.

`L"*[System/EventID= 4624]"` gives events with eventID is 4624.

`L"*[System/Level < 1]"` gives events with level < 2.

Like that I need to set the value for `pwsQuery` to get event logged near 10 seconds. Can I do in the same way as above? If so how? If not what are the other ways to do it?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having?  What does your code look like?  What is not working in it?  What symptoms are you experiencing?  Please be more specific.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EvtSubscribe()` gives you **new** events as they happen. You need to use `EvtQuery()` to get **existing** events that have already been logged.

The [Consuming Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd996910.aspx) documentation shows a sample query that retrieves events beginning at a specific time:

> ```
> // The following query selects all events from the channel or log file where the severity level is
> // less than or equal to 3 and the event occurred in the last 24 hour period.
> XPath Query: *[System[(Level &lt;= 3) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 86400000]]]
> ```

So, you can use `TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) <= 10000]` to get events in the last 10 seconds.

The `TimeCreated` element is documented here:

[TimeCreated (SystemPropertiesType) Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385211.aspx)

The `timediff()` function is described on the [Consuming Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd996910.aspx) documentation:

> The timediff function is supported. The function computes the difference between the second argument and the first argument. One of the arguments must be a literal number. The arguments must use FILETIME representation. The result is the number of milliseconds between the two times. The result is positive if the second argument represents a later time; otherwise, it is negative. When the second argument is not provided, the current system time is used.